# For what purpose is Android TextUtils used?

Tags: android, textutils

I was wondering - "why do others use TextUtils in many purposes?" - but I am not clear about this. The Developer site says that it is a simple string splitter. I understand this but I don't know how to use this in a practical manner or what purposes I can use it? Can anyone provide me some practical example with a code snippet?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is simply a set of utility functions to do operations on String objects. In fact, the whole class doesn't have any instance fields or methods. Everything is static. Consider it like a container to group functions with a text-based semantic. Many of them could have been methods of a String inherited class or CharSequence inherited class. For example you can do:

```
TextUtils.indexOf(string, char)
```

which is the same of doing

```
string.indexOf(char);
```

Many of them do things that you can already do with string public methods. Many others add additional functionalities. This class serves at a method level the same purpose that a package serves at a class level.

Answer (score 11):

one of the uses of `textUtils` is for example lets say you have a string `"apple,banana,orange,pinapple,mango"` which doesnt fit inside a given width it can be converted to `"Apple, banana, 2 more"`.

Comment: I like the idea, can you add some code for your answer.

Comment: provide some code for implementation.

Comment: Refer commaEllipsize (CharSequence text, TextPaint p, float avail, String oneMore, String more) part in the link below :    
  https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html